# Changing always_populate_raw_post_data in php.ini

Tags: apache, vagrant

Hello everyone I have a question.
I have to change the `always_populate_raw_post_data` from 0 to -1.
I made a `phpinfo()` page and there it says its set to 0.

I went to `/etc/php5/apache2` through ssh and found the php.ini file.

But for some strange reason the `always_populate_raw_post_data` was already -1.
yet `phpinfo()` says its set to 0. Where can i set this to -1 properly.

Im using a vagrant lamp stack (scotch).

Info:

OS:     Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)
PHP Version  5.6.14-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

Comment: Check the phpinfo out for what php.ini is actually used.

Comment: it says 
Loaded Configuration File /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: This is a true/false configuration flag, why do you want to set it to -1?

Comment: `phpinfo()` shows **2** values in fact: local and master. Are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, in my php.ini file `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` was set to -1 already, but it was commented. I had to uncomment it by removing the ";" which was in front of it.

so by default it looks like this:

```
;always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

But it has to be this

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
```

Note how i removed the ; in front of it.

Comment: My bad! @ÁlvaroGonzález